# What is the difference between CriteriaBuilder.createQuery and EntityManager.createQuery?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

Let's say I have the code, like:

```
EntityManager em = ...;
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.select(pet);
TypedQuery<Pet> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<Pet> allPets = q.getResultList();
```

Can some please explain why we are using two `createQuery()` methods and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`CriteriaBuilder#createQuery(Class<T> resultClass)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#createQuery-java.lang.Class-) creates [`CriteriaQuery<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html),

and
[`EntityManager#createQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery-) creates [`TypedQuery<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html).

### TL;DR:

These two types are not necessarily alternatives of each other, they rather serve a little different purposes:

`TypedQuery<T>` is used to avoid casting to the target type and `CriteriaQuery<T>` is used to define queries programmatically (instead of writing them manually). You can even use both in conjunction and I will show you - how.

---

Now, let's see this in a bit more details.

### `TypedQuery<T>`

JPA represents queries with either `Query`, `TypedQuery<T>` or `StoredProcedureQuery` instances (all from `javax.persistence` package, and latter two extend `Query`).

A simple example of using `Query` would look like this:

```java
//you write/create query
Query query = em.createQuery("your select query..");

//you get Object instance, so cast to target type is needed
SomeType result = (SomeType) query.getSingleResult();

//you get raw List instance, again - cast to target type is needed
List<SomeType> resultList = (List<SomeType>) query.getResultList();
```

Note, that `Query` API methods return either `Object` or a raw type (without specialized type) `List` instances, which you have to cast to your expected/target type.

`TypedQuery<T>`, on the other hand, differs from `Query` in a way, that you provide the class of your expected/target return value (i.e. generic type argument) when creating the query, and you thereby skip the casting part, like this:

```java
//you still write query, but here you create typed-query object
TypedQuery<SomeType> typedQuery = em.createQuery("your select query..");

//no cast needed
SomeType result = typedQuery.getSingleResult();

//no cast needed
List<SomeType> result = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

**Important** point here is, that in all these cases, *you have to write HQL or JPQL query manually* in order to construct corresponding `Query` instance, on which, you will, afterwards, invoke corresponding method(s).

### `CriteriaQuery<T>`

`CriteriaQuery<T>` is also query, so it is *conceptually* same thing as `Query` (*you build the Query against database, and you want to use that query in order to get data from/to database*), but its main purpose is to provide a *programmatic* and *type-safe* way for defining a platform-independent queries.

JPA Specification 2.2 [states](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf), that:

> The JPA Criteria API is used to define queries through the construction of object-based query definition objects, rather than use of the string-based approach of the Java Persistence query language.

So, instead of manually writing HQL/JPQL queries, you construct the query programmatically, like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SomeType> cq = cb.createQuery(SomeType.class);
Root<SomeType> root = cq.from(SomeType.class);

//programmatically adding criterias and/or some filter clauses to your query
cq.select(root);
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("id")));

//passing cq to entityManager or session object
TypedQuery<SomeType> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
List<SomeType> list =  typedQuery.getResultList();
```

---

Answering your final question - **which methods hits the database?**:

In all above cases, actual query hits the database when you invoke methods of `Query` (or its child) objects. In our examples, these are:

```
query.getSingleResult();
query.getResultList();
typedQuery.getSingleResult();
typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Remember two steps:

1. You define/construct the query object (either with `HQL`, `JPQL` or `CriteriaQuery<T>`);
2. You invoke the API methods on that object, which actually query the database.